# How to install Oracle 11 Release 2 on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: software-installation, 15.04, oracle

I am new to oracle and database domain and want to install it, I checked some tutorials on the net but I couldn't find one for Ubuntu 15.04.

I downloaded the 2 files (Linux x86-64) from:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html

Comment: What help you need?

Comment: how to install oracle 11gr2 on ubuntu 15.04?

Comment: you'll find everything you need [here](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/04/17/how-to-install-oracle-11g-r2-database-on-ubuntu-15-04-vivid-64bit-gnulinux-easy-guide/) or [here](http://www.cloudnetwork.in/2015/01/how-to-install-oracle-11g-r2-step-by.html)

Comment: @Serphiroth: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more?  **;-)**  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: @Serphiroth
step 5 i got this:
E: Unable to locate package libtiff4
E: Package 'libtiff4-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libpthread-stubs0

Comment: Try a `sudo apt install libtiff5-dev`

Answer (score -3):

Here we Go !

**1- Download the Oracle 11g R2 Database for Linux:
Oracle 11g R2 .zip for Linux**

[The Link Contains the List of Oracle 11g r2 Database Releases.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html)

**2- Open a Shell Session or Terminal Emulator Window**
`Ctrl+Alt+t`
(Press “Enter” to Execute Commands)

[image: img1]

**3- Login as SuperUser**

```
sudo su
```

If Got “User is Not in Sudoers file” then Look at the [Solution here](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2012/03/05/linuxsudoerrorisnotinthesudoersfile/).

**4- Make Network Configuration**

- Get hostname:

  hostname
- Get IP:

  /sbin/ifconfig

(You will Find It Under the lo >> inet Section.)

- Check if Hostname is Already into the Enabled Hosts File.

  cat /etc/hosts

If It’s Not Present then Insert it with:

```
nano /etc/hosts
```

Insert:

```
[myIP] [myHostname]
```

Example: ‘127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain’

Ctrl+Shift+v to Paste Content into nano

Ctrl+x to Save and Exit from nano Editor

- Grant Connection to , Server

  xhost +myIP

Example: # xhost +127.0.0.1

**5- Install Prerequisite Packages**

```
apt-get update
```

And

```
apt-get install alien autoconf automake autotools-dev binutils doxygen \
elfutils expat gawk gcc gcc-multilib g++-multilib libstdc++6:i386 ksh less libtiff4 \
libtiff4-dev lib32z1 libaio1 libaio-dev libc6-dev libc6-dev-i386 libc6-i386 \
libelf-dev libltdl-dev libmotif4 libodbcinstq4-1 libodbcinstq4-1:i386 \
libpthread-stubs0 libpth-dev libstdc++5 lsb-cxx make \
pdksh openssh-server rlwrap rpm sysstat unixodbc unixodbc-dev x11-utils \
zlibc libglapi-mesa:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 \
libpthread-workqueue0 libpthread-workqueue-dev libzthread-2.3-2 libzthread-dev \
libpthread-stubs0-dev
```

**6- Make Symlinks to Binaries and Libraries**

Linking Binaries

```
ln -s /usr/bin/awk /bin/awk

ln -s /usr/bin/rpm /bin/rpm

ln -s /usr/bin/basename /bin/basename
```

Linking Libraries

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x8664-linux-gnu /usr/lib64

cd /lib64

ln -s /lib/x8664-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 .
```

**7- Add Groups and User**

```
groupadd -g 502 oinstall

groupadd -g 503 dba

groupadd -g 504 oper

groupadd -g 505 asmadmin

useradd -u 502 -g oinstall -G dba,asmadmin,oper -s /bin/bash -m oracle

passwd oracle
```

**Take Note** of the oracle User Pass :)

**8- Make Target Directories**

```
mkdir -p /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/

chown -R oracle:oinstall /u01

chmod -R 775 /u01
```

**9- Parameters Configuration SetUp**

Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` file.

```
nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Then hit `Ctrl+x` to Save and Exit from nano Editor

**Add or amend** the following lines

```
#### Oracle 11g Kernel Parameters ####
fs.suid_dumpable = 1
fs.aio-max-nr = 1048576
fs.file-max = 6815744
kernel.shmall = 2097152
kernel.shmmax = 536870912
kernel.shmmni = 4096
# semaphores: semmsl, semmns, semopm, semmni
kernel.sem = 250 32000 100 128
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 9000 65500
net.core.rmem_default=4194304
net.core.rmem_max=4194304
net.core.wmem_default=262144
net.core.wmem_max=1048586
```

Edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` file.

```
nano /etc/security/limits.conf
```

**Add** the following lines

```
#### oracle User Settings 4 Oracle 11g ####
oracle       soft  nproc  2047
oracle       hard  nproc  16384
oracle       soft  nofile 1024
oracle       hard  nofile 65536
oracle       soft  stack  10240
```

Load the New Kernel Parameters.

```
sysctl -p
```

**10- Unzip, Set Ownership and Relocate database**

On Desktop Double-Click on Archive to Extract:

[image: img2]

Or from Command Line:

```
cd /home/[myUser]/Downloads

unzip linux_11gR2_database_1of2.zip

unzip linux_11gR2_database_2of2.zip
```

Then Set Ownership:

```
chown -R oracle:oinstall database

mv database /tmp
```

**11- Set Env. Variables & Paths for oracle’s User**

Login as Oracle

```
su oracle
```

Edit `.bashrc` file

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Append:

```
# Oracle Settings
TMP=/tmp; export TMP
TMPDIR=$TMP; export TMPDIR
ORACLE_HOSTNAME=[HOSTNAME]; export ORACLE_HOSTNAME
ORACLE_UNQNAME=DB11G; export ORACLE_UNQNAME
ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle; export ORACLE_BASE
ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1; export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=[DBSID]; export ORACLE_SID
PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH; export PATH
PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH; export PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64; export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib; export CLASSPATH
```

Replace [HOSTNAME] with IP and [DBSID] with SID Name

In this Example Respectively:

- HOSTNAME = 127.0.0.1
- DBSID = SID

Load New `.bashrc` Settings

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

**12- Install the Oracle 11g Software**

```
cd /tmp/database

./runInstaller
```

If Got Display Not Set Look:

[GetOracle 12c DB Troubleshooting](http://oracletroubleshooting.blogspot.com/2013/10/oracle-12c-database-installation.html).

[image: img3]

On the first screen Just **Leave eMail Blank and Un-Check the Demand of Security Update Support** then Click on **Next**

[image: img4]

Then **Confirm on Warning** and Follow.

[image: img5]

On “Select Installation Option” Select “**Install database software only**” and Click on **Next**

[image: img6]

On Step 3 Leave Default “Single instance database installation” and Click on **Next**

[image: img7]

On Step 4 Select your **Language** and Click on **Next**

[image: img8]

On Step 5 Leave Default **Enterprise Edition** and Click on **Next**

[image: img9]

On “Installation Location” **Set All As Here Below** and Click on **Next**

- Oracle Base: `/u01/app/oracle`
- Software Location: `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1`

These are the **Same Settings** Inserted into the `.bash_profile` File…

[image: img10]

On “Create Inventory” **if you Setup the Path on `.bash_profile` Like Here** Leave Default and Click on **Next**

[image: img11]

On “Operating System Groups” **if you Setup the Path on `.bash_profile` Like Here Leave Default and Click on **Next**

[image: img12]

On “Prerequisite Checks” you will Get Easily a “**Warning Message**” about some **Missing Requirements**

**Just Check: “Ignore All”** and Follow Up with Installation…

Check **Ignore All** and Follow…

[image: img13]

On the “Summary” Click on “**Save Response File**” to Take Note of Settings and then Click on **Finish**

[image: img14]

The Installation Product Procedure should Start…

**13- Execute Scripts**

Right Before the End of Process a Pop-Up Window will Show the Path to Two Configuration Scripts you Need to Execute on Terminal !

[image: img14]

Next Oracle Should Confirm you of the Successful Installation Achivement.

[image: img15]

After you Should Access the “Enterprise Manager” on Browser by the URL shown on the Latest Screen.

On a Localhost for Example you Should Access the Enterprise Manager by the Address:

```
https://127.0.0.1:1158/em
```

And you can **Login** with:
User Name: **SYS**

Password: **oracleDatabasePassword**

From the Drop-down below **Select >> Connect as SYSDBA**

You Should be Able to Access the Database by the Enterprise Manager!

(The Source [Source](http://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/04/17/how-to-install-oracle-11g-r2-database-on-ubuntu-15-04-vivid-64bit-gnulinux-easy-guide/))

Comment: while step 5" Install Prerequisite Packages"
I got this:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libtiff4-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libtiff5-dev:i386 libtiff5-dev

E: Unable to locate package libtiff4
E: Package 'libtiff4-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libpthread-stubs0

Comment: Why would you be making symlinks for awk? Why for `basename`? Why would those need to be in `/bin`? Why in the _world_ would you be creating a `/lib54` directory? How is rpm even relevant to an Ubuntu question? What is `/u01` supposed to be?